# Is this the right approach to table creation in DynamoDB?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

My understanding of a NoSQL store such as Dynamo or Mongo etc. is that you should be thinking in terms of denormalization and creating tables based around the queries you will be performing.

I am struggling with how I should setup my table.

I've identified the queries that I want to run.

I've translated what would be a normal SQL query into 'plain english'

For example, a query that I want to run would translate as so:

"Get all photos taken between date_x and date_y where the photographer is John ordered by most votes"

Since I can't do table joins, this is what I came up with:

```
photos
{
    name,
    url,
    photographer,
    date_created,
    likes,
    dislikes,
    num_voters,
    weighted_score
}
```

Is this the right approach?

The reason I have the likes, dislikes, num_voters, and weighted_score is because I believe, whenever a user votes on a photo, I need to update the "row" and increment likes/dislikes/num_voters and re-calculate the weighted_score (so that highly rated items with a low number of voters don't affect my leaderboards)

However,

Because I am applying 'filters' -- I assume a key/value store like Dynamo is not what I want?

Also one side question: Let's say I have a photographers table, and I want to delete a photographer. Is it my responsibility to then go through photos and delete by photographer? Again, since it's non-relational, I assume there is no cascading type features?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB is a indexed key-value database that currently only allows you to define a primary key as well as a range key for each table.  It is probably not well-suited for your flexible querying example as searching by multiple attributes will end up doing [non-indexed table scans](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/#Can_I_make_a_query_based_on_a_non-primary_key_attribute).

MongoDB is a document-oriented database which allows you to define multiple indexes, and would be a better fit for your use case.

eg: "Get all photos taken between date_x and date_y where the photographer is John ordered by most votes".

```
db.photos.find({
    'photographer': 'john',
    'created': {
        $gte: ISODate("2012-07-01"),
        $lte: ISODate("2012-07-05")
    }
}).sort({'votes': -1});
```

For incrementing counters such as the number of likes/dislikes/votes, see [Atomic Operations](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations).

You are correct that cascading delete is not supported (or relevant) for a non-relational database.  You could support this logic in your application layer by deleting related documents.  Some MongoDB drivers do support a notion of [Database References (DBRefs)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/) which can be useful to fetch related documents.  Use of DBRefs would still result in multiple queries, but can be a useful helper.